# Decent-performance sequential container for both middle inserts, and random access

Tags: c++, containers, big-o

I am making a small card game, that due to odd game-rules need to do frequent
middle inserts, and frequent random access. I used a std::list for this, and that is
with good margin fast enough for PvsP, but now I am making the AI, which uses brute-force
to find a good move (The game is deterministic), and them Big-O(n) is hurting.

Now on to my question; is there a free, **sequential**, probably tree-based, STL-like,
well tested container with Big-O of no more than log(n) for both middle insert and random access?

Note: I am **not** looking for an associative container.

Update: I found a thing called `AVL-Array` that does what I want. It fulfils all requirements except 'well tested'. It gave me the speed-up I was hoping for, but unfortunately the destructor seems buggy and slow.

New Update: All problems I had with `AVL-Array` where caused by my debugger (!), and
I have now settled on it.

Comment: `middle inserts` = inserting at the middle of the list? in this case is the list sorted or something like this?

Comment: middle insert in this case is inserting in any position that is not either end. the list is not sorted

Comment: What on earth is `std-like`?

Comment: OMGtechy: similar to the functions/classes in the std-library.

Comment: OMGtechy: mayby I should have written STL-like

Comment: if the list is not sorted how do you currently find a random element? Can you retrieve his index precisely or do you have to iterate?

Comment: random access means index?

Comment: UmNyobe: precisely; I know the index based on the value of a previously drawn card. D.R: yes

Comment: Do the indexes stay constant (e.g. you insert "B" between "A" and "C") or do they behave like array-indices (i.e. if you insert something [0] and [1] then [1] is moved to [2])?

Comment: And furthermore: is there a requirement that the indices are bound to some underlying rule (e.g. 0,1,2,3,4 ...) or may they be SomeGuid, SomeOtherGuid, AnotherGuid, ...

Comment: D.R: I am looking for a **sequential** container, i.e. it should behave like std::vector

Comment: Did you actually try std::vector?

Comment: Obviously we have different definitions for sequential. Associative containers can be sequential too, a sequential container's only property is (according to my defintition) that it can be enumerated one element after the other.

Comment: So, you benchmarked that linked list is too slow? Presumably, with the AI, you're doing much more random access than you do middle inserts. Perhaps the O(n) cost of middle insertion into a `vector` is negligible. As Jon already said, did you try that?

Comment: After summarizing all the requirements I guess its simply not possible to have such a container.

Comment: I benchmarked already; vector was marginally slower than list. Middle-inserts and random-access are roughly equally frequent. (end-remove is also relatively frequent)

Comment: did you also profile *what* made list and vector so slow? Did you try deque?

Comment: Regarding `deque`; I don't insert/remove in the front, but I will try for good measure. Regarding the reason for being slow; It is that the depht-first, alfa-beta-cutof, brute-force algorithm executes trillions of `MakeMove`, not that each of 'em is slow.

Comment: I've stumbled upon project [AVL-array](http://sourceforge.net/projects/avl-array/) which should be just what you're looking for, but I have no idea how finished/usable that code is.

Answer (score 0):

A "small card game" does not sound too performance-critical. So, my first choice would be a `std::vector`. The time spent in middle inserts there will me in the order of #of inserts times #of elements times size of elements. I doubt that any of those are very huge, with huge meaning in the order of millions of elements, millinos of inserts or kb of element sizes.

Try to use implementations with the containers at hand, and make performance measurements. The list you have is likely to make the random access a performance loss, while it is O(1) in `std::vector`. Middle inserts on the other hand may be fastest in `std::list`, but if your vector elements are trivial, the insertion is mainly a simple memmove and not very expensive.

In general, **when in doubt, use a profiler**. It is the only thing (including other humans) which can tell you how good the compiler optimizes your code.

Comment: The performance critical part is the brute-force part of the ai. It work similar to how you would do a chess-program. If I can make it faster, it can search deeper, and will play better.